Finding ArcSin or ArcCos from other mathmatical functions
I have an elderly CNC milling machine, which I tend to program with universal, parameter driven programs. To make one of these programs work, I really need an ArcSin or ArcCos function, ideally in degrees (I'm machining complex compound curves, the machine controller requires me to program helical tool moves using polar co-ordinates)
Available functions I can use are: Addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, square root, sin (in degrees), cos (in degrees). With a little bit of cunning I can do powers of x  or similar (running a loop with a function in n times).
Ideally I need to write a function that returns an answer in degrees accurate to 3 decimal places for the full input interval 0 - 1.
Any suggestions?

Have you considered a Taylor series approximation for your functions? Perhaps the first few terms? Also your input will be in. [1, -1] probably shouldn't get too large even if you use a very high order Taylor series

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50894477/8550319, you may need many terms from the Taylor series for a precise result, so they recommend approximating arctan instead and transforming form there

@Kraken Yes, I tried what I think were the first 4 terms of a Taylor series, it wasn't a million miles out at x = 0.866 (should be 60 degs, I got 60.875), it's was wildly of at x = 1 (I got something like 75 degs).

I see, @Milten's suggestion is nice as well. You might also try using a continued fraction approach, but I am unaware of how fast it converges. You can compute them via recurrence relations. See here for a continued fraction for the arcsin function.

Series are going to run into problems because of how vertical both functions get close to $x=1$. Instead to get that shape, the function $(90-10.29437x)\sqrt{1-x}$ always gets you to within a degree, an error of at most $0.32$ degrees. The error is also $0$ at the endpoints and at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ so if you want more precision, keep adding terms of the form $a\sin(n\pi x)$ for integer $n$.

Sorry for clarity, even integer $n$

I happen to have  a pretty good function for calculating $\arccos$ for positive argument which is based on minimax polynomial approximation.
For $x \in [0, 1]$: $\arccos(x) \approx \sqrt{1 - x} \cdot (1.5707963267948966 - 0.20347053865798365 x + 0.046887774236182234 x^2)$
For $x \in [-1, 0]$, use that $\arccos(-x)=\pi-\arccos(x)$
Link to the source: https://www.geometrictools.com/
This second degree minimax polynomial approximation has max absolute error less than $0.001$ radian and max relative error less than $0.06\%$

Maybe add how accurate it is (it seems the maximum error is $\sim 0.06%$).

And the largest absolute error is about $0.00082$ at $x\approx0.172$. So it's just about accurate to $3$ decimal places, but not more than that (and it can happen that the third decimal place as such is different).

@Milten: Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the answer.

I'm realizing that OP was looking for an accuracy to $3$ decimal places in degrees. This has maximum absolute error $\approx 0.047$ degrees, which may not be good enough for OP then...

This may be very helpful, but isn't without challenges for my application. 0.047 degrees may be accurate enough, it depends on the CNC control's behavior - I know I'm safe at 3DP. The other complication is that in the control system, variables have a maximum length of 8 significant figures (you're using 17), and to make things even harder, that is fixed with three decimal places!

@JohnEastwood: if you round the coefficients to 3 decimals, it is still pretty good approximation with max absolute error around $0.001$. You can't expect better than that.
